# Errors during compiling C program but this code worked on other computer

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I used this program on ssh connexion, but I wanted to download it for a better analysis. So I copied it manually, and I compiled it with gcc using this command :

```
C:\Users\Joachim>gcc ch72.c -o ch
```

and a lot of error occured, and I can't understand them :

```
ch72.c: In function `main':
ch72.c:18: parse error before `int'
ch72.c:18: `i' undeclared (first use in this function)
ch72.c:18: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
ch72.c:18: for each function it appears in.)
ch72.c:18: parse error before `)'
ch72.c:19: `__x' undeclared (first use in this function)
ch72.c: At top level:
ch72.c:19: parse error before `)'
ch72.c:21: parse error before string constant
ch72.c:21: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

My code  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define DEFAULT_LEN 16

void admin_shell(void)
{
    system("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
}

int main(void)
{
    char buff[DEFAULT_LEN] = {0};

    gets(buff);
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_LEN; i++) {
        buff[i] = toupper(buff[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

I tried to understand erros but I haven't achieved to : what is a parse error ?? Why it is talking about __x ? The fact that the code worked on the ssh server brought me to thought that it's a problem of libraries or other stuff like that but the errors aren't very expressive about dependancies so I don't know what think about that...
If anyone know what happend I would be grateful.

Comment: Your local compiler is defaulting to conformance with a different (very old) version of the C language specification than the remote compiler does.  Try adding the option `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11` to your compilation command line.

Comment: He doen't recognize this option, but maybe there is a way to upgrade C language version ?

Comment: What does `gcc -v` print out?

Comment: `Reading specs from C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\specs
gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release)`

Comment: Good heavens, your C compiler is 23 years old.  Buy it a beer, then uninstall it and install something from this century.

Comment: Okay xdd, yes may be that's a good idea :). But how  is it possible I got this pc 5 years ago ?

Comment: Apparently you, or someone else, downloaded and installed a very old version.  Only you or they know why or how.

Comment: Cygwin is an add-on, not part of Windows itself.  Whoever installed Cygwin on your machine installed that version, which was already obsolete at the time.  Why they chose that one is going to be impossible for us to determine.  There are much newer Cygwin releases, or you could consider opting for mingw-w64 instead.

Comment: Yes I understand, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

the syntax "for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_LEN; i++) {" where you declare the loop variable within the for statement is not a valid C code in its older versions.
You may want to change it to two lines, one to declare i, and then the for loop that uses the previously declared i.
Or get a compiler that supports modern C syntax.